# Virtual Box CD/DVD-ROM

Tags: virtualbox, compact-disc

I'm trying to install Virtual Box under **Ubuntu 10.10**, but I had the following problem:

When trying to install Windows XP from CD, I went into the settings of my VM, but I can't see the **CD/DVD-ROM tab**.  I see System, Screen, Storage.... But I can't see the CD/DVD-ROM.

Any thoughts what it can be happening, or what can I do?

If more info is needed, let me know and I will update the post.

**UPDATE**

Here is the "problem".  I can't see the CD/DVD-ROM on the left column:
If I can't see that on the left side, I am not able to Mount the CD with the Operating System I'm trying to install...

[image: VirtualBox CD/DVD-ROM PNG]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be found under VM Settings > Storage.
[image]

Comment: I've done that, and now I have under IDE Controller my CD/DVD, but it still does not appear in the settings on the left of your picture.

Comment: @Nobita, is it possible for you to grab a screenshot of the settings and upload it to imgur.com and insert it into your original question?

Comment: Yes, that's better.  I did that.

Comment: @Nobita, untick the "passthrough" checkbox. I'm fairly sure the "TSSTCorp..." is your host machine CD/DVD drive.

Comment: Solved. I miunderstood all the working of the CD/DVD-ROM.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Under Storage:

Select the IDE controller and click on the icon that looks like a CD with a + sign on it.

Select the new Empty CD device and configure as necessary.